# The variation of the Lagrangian density for the canonical energy-momentum tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I expanded the Lagrangian to this form
$$ \mathcal{L} = -{1 \over 4} F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} = ... = - {1 \over 2} (\partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu} - \partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} \partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}). $$

Now, I know that the result of
${{ \delta \mathcal{L}} \over {\delta (\partial_{\mu} A_{\lambda})}} $ is $ - F^{\mu \lambda}$, but I dunno exactly why. I tried to put the Lagrangian density there
$$ {{\partial \mathcal{L}} \over {\partial (\partial_{\mu} A_{\lambda})}} = - {1 \over 2} {{\partial} \over {\partial (\partial_{\mu} A_{\lambda})}} (\partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu} - \partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} \partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}) = - {1 \over 2} \cdot 2 (\partial^{\mu} A^{\lambda} - \partial^{\lambda} A^{\mu}) $$
but I can't see whether is sufficient or I probably got the indices wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is correct but you shouldn't have got it from the method you used (yours would be a factor of $1/2$ out). To do it correctly you need to lower all the indices of $\partial^{\mu} A^{\mu}$ in order to properly do the partial derivative: i.e.
$$ \partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} = g^{\mu \rho} g^{\nu \sigma} \partial_{\rho} A_{\sigma} \ .$$
Now if you use this for both terms in $F^{\mu \nu}$, and then do the partial derivative of this with respect to $\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}$ using the chain rule etc, you will get the correct result.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your answer. Now it seems clear to me and I was able to get the proper answer. Taking this opportunity, can I ask one more question? Because, now I was able to put this result to this equation:
$ T^{\mu \nu} = - F^{\mu \lambda} \partial^{\nu} A_{\lambda} + {1 \over 4} \eta^{\mu \nu} F^{\rho \sigma} F_{\rho \sigma} $
Well, I actually had to consider a new tensor $ \hat{T}^{\mu \nu} = T^{\mu \nu} + \partial_{\lambda} K^{\lambda \mu \nu}$
because that procedure yielded a nonsymmetric tensor. And now, the question is - what is the trace of $\hat{T}^{\mu \nu}$

Comment: @Chakalaka, I see you've already asked this in another question now :) If you could accept my answer above that'd be appreciated!